# ImageView overlay not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 layouts in my xml, a CircularImageView and a ImageView, and the ImageView must appear on top of the CircularImageView.

I've tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_register_ll_kid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_img_kids"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_boy"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_iv_crown"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_kids_row_img_kids"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-22dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_crown"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_tv_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="1 ano e 4 meses"
            android:textColor="#808080"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it is getting cut off:
[image]

I need the image to be shown exactly at that position in the picture, but not "cropped", what I am missing here ?

BTW, this component is part of a RecyclerView row.

EDIT ---
**I forgot to mention, the image is just a placeholder to show the Avatar, but the image is dinamically populated !**

Thanks !

Comment: The problem here is the negative margins

Comment: you could put the second imageview in the center of the parent (horizontally) and use positive margins to offset it where you want it, instead of putting it right of the other view and using negative margins... it seems like you can keep the view aligned to the top of the parent so you can leave that alone probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding (16dp)  that you are applying to the first relativeLayout makes you think that there is more place and that you can move up the imageView. Actually the margin is like a gap, it doesn't extend your layout.

This is the solution I suggest , using a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

       <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_img_kids"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_boy"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_kids_row_iv_crown"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_crown"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT :**  You don't have to use a frameLayout, you can use a relativeLayout if you want to set different margins. The point here is really to make your containing layout bigger so you can place the `imageview easily`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one image to be on top of another, why you use `android:layout_toRightOf`?
Remove it and second image should cover first one.
Also you can try to remove margins at second image and use `centerInParent`, `centerVertically` or `centerHorizontally`.
Or maybe I didn't got all the problem ) then pls provide more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Using an image editor like Paint/Photoshop and merging the two images? Then you can just display one image in your view.

Answer (score 0):

try using a linear layout with the orientation set to vertical.